# Command line script in windows

Tags: php, windows

I am trying to run a php script from the command line in windows using the following variations:

```
php script.php
php -f script.php
```

Both commands just print out the entire script but don't execute the script.

Comment: Is php in your path enviroment variable? Does putting the full path to your PHP executable work? /path/to/php script.php

Comment: If it wasn't, then there would be an error about php not being found, not the behaviour described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without contents of the script its difficult to see the issues.

Most likely is that you have not used `<?php ?>` tags or used the short hand.  Try using the full `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you forgot to start the script with `<?php`.

Content in a PHP script outside of a `<?php` block goes direct to STDOUT.